# Couchbase attempt context transaction not working as expected

Tags: couchbase, distributed-transactions, spring-data-couchbase, couchbase-java-api

When there are multiple requests for updating same document in a AttemptContext transaction block, data becomes inconsistent because of concurrent threads trying to update the document. Also a warning message

`[com.couchbase.core][IllegalDocumentState] Tried committing document <document_id>, but found that it has been modified by another party in-between staging and committing. The application must ensure that non-transactional writes cannot happen at the same time as transactional writes on a document. The change will be committed with CAS=0, which will overwrite the other change. This document may need manual review to verify that no changes have been lost. Last document state=cas=<CAS>,seqno=<SEQ_NO>,vbucket`

This leaves data inconsistent.

Comment: What version of Spring are you using? What version of Couchbase are you using?

Comment: Please see followup on https://forums.couchbase.com/t/couchbase-attempt-context-transaction-not-working-as-expected/33903